# How to type from stdin to file (or port) in powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

In `cmd.exe` I can type `copy con <filename>` and write whatever to file, or com1, for example. Can I do same things in powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#here-strings) and redirect it to a file:

```
@'
type 
your
lines
here
'@ > file.txt
```

Note:

- Both the opening (`@'`) and the closing delimiter (`'@`) must be on their own lines and that the closing delimiter must be at the very start of the line.

  - If you use `@"` and `"@` instead, you get an [*expandable*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) here-string, i.e. on with string interpolation, allowing you to reference variables and embed expressions and command output.
- Interactively, every line but the first will be prefixed with the line-continuation prompt string, `>>` , which I've omitted for conceptual clarity above.

---

Note: As [postatnote](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9132707/postanote) points out, you don't strictly need a *here-string* for this, as even regular `'...'` (verbatim) and `"..."` (interpolating) strings can span multiple lines, but use of here-strings has two distinct advantages:

- You needn't worry about *escaping* `'` or `"` in the content of the string.
- Having the opening and closing delimiters on their own line makes for clearer visual separation (if you tried `'<newline>type...'`, for instance, the newline would become part of the content).

Comment: One can also do this in the PowerShell console without the use of the `@` as well, single/double quote works. Yet, I am taken aback as to why one would do this. Notepad, ISE, come to mind as more prudent options. Even on Windows Server Core, Notepad is there and usable as normal.

Comment: Fair point, @postanote, but please see my update as to why here-strings are preferable. As for why would someone would do this: Sure, an editor is generally more convenient, but as a low-ceremony option for creating a file interactively, without having to switch to a different application, it can be useful.

Comment: Agreed, but, it one can create and run that way, but if you then need to change it, for whatever reason, then you need an editor to do so, or end up doing and a ton of Get-Content/Select-String and replace stuff. Well, choices have to be made. Yet, if you are in a situation, where notepad is not usable, due to memory, then, it's time to do something about that host.  ***;-}** --- or find an `DOS edlin` clone. and carry that as a portable app on a USB stick or CD/DVD.  ***;-}***